# pandas Timestamp components - some are properties and some are methods?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've been playing around with the pandas Time/Date components described in the docs, and I've noticed that of the Time/Date components listed http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components, some of them are properties and some of them are methods. Examples:

[image: output]

Is there an explanation for this in the docs and/or an overall logic to which components are properties and which are methods?

Answer (score 1):

If I refer your example, Then:

```
pd.Timestamp
```

is the property. Any direct pandas operation is a pandas property.

Below are some possibilities:

```
In [4]: pd.
Display all 158 possibilities? (y or n)
pd.Categorical           pd.SparseTimeSeries      pd.ewmvol                pd.io                    pd.read_excel            pd.rolling_sum
pd.CategoricalIndex      pd.Term                  pd.expanding_apply       pd.isnull                pd.read_fwf              pd.rolling_var
pd.DataFrame             pd.TimeGrouper           pd.expanding_corr        pd.json                  pd.read_gbq              pd.rolling_window
pd.DateOffset            pd.TimeSeries            pd.expanding_count       pd.lib                   pd.read_hdf              pd.scatter_matrix
pd.DatetimeIndex         pd.Timedelta             pd.expanding_cov         pd.lreshape              pd.read_html             pd.set_eng_float_format
pd.ExcelFile             pd.TimedeltaIndex        pd.expanding_kurt        pd.match                 pd.read_json             pd.set_option
pd.ExcelWriter           pd.Timestamp             pd.expanding_max         pd.melt                  pd.read_msgpack          pd.show_versions
pd.Expr                  pd.WidePanel             pd.expanding_mean        pd.merge                 pd.read_pickle           pd.sparse
pd.Float64Index          pd.algos                 pd.expanding_median      pd.missing_dependencies  pd.read_sas              pd.stats
pd.Grouper               pd.bdate_range           pd.expanding_min         pd.msgpack               pd.read_sql              pd.test
pd.HDFStore              pd.compat                pd.expanding_quantile    pd.notnull               pd.read_sql_query        pd.timedelta_range
pd.Index                 pd.computation           pd.expanding_skew        pd.np                    pd.read_sql_table        pd.to_datetime
pd.IndexSlice            pd.concat                pd.expanding_std         pd.offsets               pd.read_stata            pd.to_msgpack
pd.Int64Index            pd.core                  pd.expanding_sum         pd.ols                   pd.read_table            pd.to_numeric
pd.MultiIndex            pd.crosstab              pd.expanding_var         pd.option_context        pd.reset_option          pd.to_pickle
pd.NaT                   pd.cut                   pd.factorize             pd.options               pd.rolling_apply         pd.to_timedelta
pd.Panel                 pd.date_range            pd.fama_macbeth          pd.ordered_merge         pd.rolling_corr          pd.tools
pd.Panel4D               pd.datetime              pd.get_dummies           pd.pandas                pd.rolling_count         pd.tseries
pd.Period                pd.datetools             pd.get_option            pd.parser                pd.rolling_cov           pd.tslib
pd.PeriodIndex           pd.dependency            pd.get_store             pd.period_range          pd.rolling_kurt          pd.unique
pd.RangeIndex            pd.describe_option       pd.groupby               pd.pivot                 pd.rolling_max           pd.util
pd.Series                pd.eval                  pd.hard_dependencies     pd.pivot_table           pd.rolling_mean          pd.value_counts
pd.SparseArray           pd.ewma                  pd.hashtable             pd.plot_params           pd.rolling_median        pd.wide_to_long
pd.SparseDataFrame       pd.ewmcorr               pd.index                 pd.pnow                  pd.rolling_min           
pd.SparseList            pd.ewmcov                pd.indexes               pd.qcut                  pd.rolling_quantile      
pd.SparsePanel           pd.ewmstd                pd.infer_freq            pd.read_clipboard        pd.rolling_skew          
pd.SparseSeries          pd.ewmvar                pd.info                  pd.read_csv              pd.rolling_std
```

The further drill-down operations in those properties are methods.

from your example:

```
t.dayofweek

t.weekday
```

are methods.